# Proving the asymptotic normality of th Non-linear Least Squares estimator

Tags: econometrics

Our model is $Y=X(\beta_0)+u$, where $u\sim IID(0,\sigma_0^2I)$, and $X(\beta)$ is a non-linear function of the beta.

When trying to minimize the $SSR(\beta)$ we get the following FOC:

$\nabla X(\beta)^T(Y-X(\beta))=0$, where $\nabla X(\beta)$ is the gradient.

Well, the FOC is equivalent to $n^{(-1/2)}(\nabla X(\beta)^T(X(\beta_0)+u-X(\beta))=0$.

If we apply a taylor expansion of the first order to each component $X_t(\beta)$ of $X(\beta)$, we obtain $X_t(\beta)=X_t(\beta_0)+\nabla X(\bar\beta_{(t)})^T(\beta-\beta_0)$, where $\bar\beta_{(t)}$ is a point in the line segment that joins $\beta$ and $\beta_0$. This point may be different for each taylor expansion we do, and that's why it's indexed by $t$.

Inserting the taylor expansion in the FOC:
$n^{(-1/2)}(\nabla X(\beta)^T(u-\nabla \bar X^T(\beta-\beta_0))=0$, where $\nabla \bar X$ is the matrix with $\nabla X(\bar\beta_{(i)})$ as each i-th column.

Are all of the above calculations correct? I ask this because in this [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Econometric-Theory-Methods-International-Edition/dp/0195391055?ie=UTF8&ref_=asap_bc), the authors state in page 225 that we should obtain a term with second derivatives of $X(\beta)$... I do not understand why this is.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that what you do is not a Taylor expansion, but an application of the mean-value theorem (as one should). If it was a Taylor expansion, apart from the remainder, the gradient would have to be evaluated at $\beta_0$. With the mean-value theorem, there is no remainder, and you evaluate the gradient at some $\bar \beta$ that always lies between $\beta$ and $\hat \beta$.

As regards the issue of second derivatives/Hessian, officially speaking they/it only "temporarily" appear in the derivation of asymptotic normality of the non-linear least -squares estimator, but they vanish asymptotically (while in the Maximum likelihood estimator the Hessian stays there).

Apart from that, we want to minimize the *sum* of squared residuals so, indexing the observations by $i$, and using much simpler notation (you will have to adjust it to vector-matrix notation), you set out to minimize $\sum_i[u_i(\beta)]^2 = \sum_i[y_i-h(\mathbf x_i,\beta)]^2$ w.r. to the vector $\beta$, in order to obtain a $\hat \beta$. So your FOC is (suppressing the regressors and passing the $i$ index to the function $h$)

$$\hat \beta : \sum_i\frac {\partial }{\partial \beta}[y_i-h_i(\beta)]^2 = 0 \implies \sum_i2[y_i-h_i(\hat \beta)] \frac {\partial h_i (\hat \beta)}{\partial \beta} =0, $$

Ignore "$2$" and apply the mean value theorem *to the whole expression*  to get

$$\sum_i[y_i-h_i(\beta)] \frac {\partial h_i (\hat \beta)}{\partial \beta} =  \sum_i[y_i-h_i(\beta_0)] \frac {\partial h_i (\beta_0)}{\partial \beta} \\ 
+ (\hat \beta -\beta) \sum_i\left [-\frac {\partial h_i (\bar \beta)}{\partial \beta}\frac {\partial h_i (\bar \beta)}{\partial \beta}+ [y_i-h_i(\bar \beta)]\frac {\partial^2 h_i (\bar \beta)}{\partial \beta^2}\right] =0$$

Note that $y_i-h_i(\beta_0) = u_i$, the true error, divide by $1/n$ and then multiply by $\sqrt n$ as you are allowed to and re-arrange to get

$$\sqrt n (\hat \beta -\beta) = -\left (\frac 1n\sum_i\left [-\frac {\partial h_i (\bar \beta)}{\partial \beta}\frac {\partial h_i (\bar \beta)}{\partial \beta}\right] + \frac 1n\sum_i\left [[y_i-h_i(\bar \beta)]\frac {\partial^2 h_i (\bar \beta)}{\partial \beta^2}\right]\right)^{-1} \cdot \left(\frac 1{\sqrt n} \sum_iu_i \frac {\partial h_i (\beta_0)}{\partial \beta} \right) $$

Now, we consider asymptotic normality, *given* that consistency holds,  $\hat \beta \xrightarrow{p} \beta_0$. Since $\bar \beta$ is sandwiched between $\hat \beta$ and $\beta_0$, it follows that $\bar \beta \xrightarrow{p} \beta_0$ also. This means that

$$\frac 1n\sum_i\left [[y_i-h_i(\bar \beta)]\frac {\partial^2 h_i (\bar \beta)}{\partial \beta^2}\right] \xrightarrow{p} \frac 1n\sum_i\left [[y_i-h_i(\beta_0)]\frac {\partial^2 h_i (\beta_0)}{\partial \beta^2}\right] \\= \frac 1n\sum_i\left [E(u_i) E\frac {\partial^2 h_i (\beta_0)}{\partial \beta^2}\right] =0$$

because $E(u_i) =0$.

So this term vanishes asymptotically and we are left with (cancelling also the negative sings)

$$\sqrt n (\hat \beta -\beta) \xrightarrow{d} \left (\text {plim}\frac 1n\sum_i\left [\frac {\partial h_i (\beta_0)}{\partial \beta}\frac {\partial h_i (\beta_0)}{\partial \beta}\right] \right)^{-1} \cdot \left(\frac 1{\sqrt n} \sum_iu_i \frac {\partial h_i (\beta_0)}{\partial \beta} \right) $$

You have to assume that the first sum converges to something positive definite, and the second converges in distribution to a normal random variable, and you do indeed make these assumptions (or deeper ones that lead to them). I don't have the specific book you mention, but you can compare the above to Davidson & McKinnon "Econometric Theory and Methods"(2004) ch. 6, around eq. $(6.30)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Alecos. It has helped a lot. ;)

Comment: Alecos, would you mind checking if my answer below is correct? Maybe I could have used a more useful notation. Feel free to edit it, if you would like to. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Alecos Papadopoulos answer, I'm posting an answer with matrix notation.
I'll change the notation a bit, to make it easier to understand.

The FOC is $D_\mathbf{x}( \beta )^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}(\beta))=0$. This gives a function in $\beta$, where $D_\mathbf{x}( \beta )$ is a matrix of dim $N\times K$, with element $\frac{\partial x_n}{\partial\beta_k}(\beta)$.

So, applying the Taylor expansion(1st order)/mean-value theorem to each component of the LHS of the equality, we obtain

\begin{equation}
D_\mathbf{x}(\beta_0)^T \mathbf{u} +\big[H_\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta)-D_\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta)^T D_\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta)\big](\hat\beta-\beta_0)=0 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(a)}
\end{equation}

where $H_\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta)$ represents a matrix $K\times K$, with each element being $H_{ij}(\bar\beta_i)[\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta_i)]$, where $H_{ij}(\bar\beta_i)=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial^2 x_1}{\partial\beta_j\partial\beta_i}(\bar\beta_i) & \dots  & \frac{\partial^2 x_n}{\partial\beta_j\partial\beta_i}(\bar\beta_i) 
\end{bmatrix}$. 
Similarly, $D_\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta)^T D_\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta)$ is the Gramian of $D_\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta)$, with $ij$-th element $\sum_l^n\frac{\partial x_l}{\partial\beta_j}(\bar\beta_i)\frac{\partial x_l}{\partial\beta_i}(\bar\beta_i)$.

From (a), $n^{\frac{1}{2}}(\hat\beta-\beta_0)=-\left(\frac{1}{n}H_\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta)-\frac{1}{n}D_\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta)^T D_\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta)\right)^{-1}n^{-\frac{1}{2}}D_\mathbf{x}(\beta_0)^T \mathbf{u}$.

We know from the non-linear model that $n^{-\frac{1}{2}}D_\mathbf{x}(\beta_0)^T \mathbf{u}=n^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_i^n u_i D_{\mathbf{x}i}(\beta_0)^T\rightarrow^d N\left(\underbrace{E(u_i D_{\mathbf{x}i}(\beta_0)^T)}_{=\mathbf{0}},\underbrace{\lim 1/n \sum E(u_i^2 D_{\mathbf{x}i}(\beta_0)D_{\mathbf{x}i}(\beta_0)^T)}_{\sigma_0^2 S_{D_0^TD_0}}\right)$

by a CLT.

Since we know that $\bar \beta\rightarrow^p \beta_0$, we have $\frac{1}{n}H_\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta)\rightarrow^p \left[\frac{1}{n}\sum \underbrace{E\left( \underbrace{(y_i-x_i\beta_0)}_{=u_i}\frac{\partial^2 x_1}{\partial\beta_j\partial\beta_i}(\beta_0)\right)}_{=0}\right]_{K\times K}=\mathbf{0}$.

Similarly, we have that $\frac{1}{n}D_\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta)^T D_\mathbf{x}(\bar\beta)\rightarrow^p S_{D_0^TD_0}$.

Thus, we can conclude that $n^{\frac{1}{2}}(\hat\beta-\beta_0)\rightarrow^p N(\mathbf{0},\sigma_0^2 S_{D_0^TD_0}^{-1})$.

Comment: Looks ok.The Asymptotic variance depends on the error being homoskedastic and non-autocorrelated of course.

Comment: Opportunity taken, please consider also upvoting answers you find helpful (apart from the green mark). I think various statistics related to the site take into account only votes and not green marks.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Done! and Thanks for the review. ;)